# Pandas read_table with sep = '::'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm going through *Python for Data Analysis* and in Chapter 2 there are introductory examples I'm working through.  On page 27 it shows the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
users = pd.read_table('ml-1m/users.dat', sep='::', header=None,
names=unames)
```

Here's a link to the github .dat file:
https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/tree/2nd-edition/datasets/movielens

When this code is run I get the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\d.kelly\Desktop\Python\PforDA>pforda.py
C:\Users\d.kelly\Desktop\Python\PforDA\PforDA.py:3: ParserWarning: Falling back
to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators
(separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can
 avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  users = pd.read_table('users.dat', sep = '::', header = None, names = unames)
```

I'm using Anaconda and Python 3 - pretty sure the book was written for Python 2.7, but I would still like to know how to get this example to work without the error messages. Wes is a smart guy and I'm sure having 2 digit separators is something I'll encounter again.

My question is, in Python 3 what is the right way to use Pandas's read_table to read 2 digit separators and not get warnings?

Comment: Use `engine='python'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter `header=None` is not necessary because is defined parameter `names`, for avoid warning add `engine='python'`:

```
unames = ['a','b','c', 'd']
users = pd.read_table('users.dat', sep='::', names=unames, engine='python')
#alternative
#users = pd.read_csv('users.dat', sep='::', names=unames, engine='python')
print (users.head())
   a   b   c      d
1  F   1  10  48067
2  M  56  16  70072
3  M  25  15  55117
4  M  45   7  02460
5  M  25  20  55455
```

Difference between [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) and [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) is in default separator, if define custom both working same way.

> **pandas.read_table**
> sep : str, default t (tab-stop)
>
> **pandas.read_csv**
> sep : str, default ','